# Following Test Automation best practise of "Methods return other PageObjects" in Ruby

Tags: ruby, testing, automation, calabash, pageobjects

I am a big advocate of the Page Object Pattern (POP) as defined by the experts at Selenium:
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects

A key view of theirs that I have always followed when using Appium with Java is:
"Methods return other PageObjects"

```
e.g. LoginPage loginPage = homePage.gotoLoginPage();
```

I am now trying to following POP using Calabash with Ruby and so have been writing code like this:

```
e.g. @login_page = @home_page.goto_login_page
```

However, since Ruby doesn't know what type of object @login_page is or @home_page is, you dont get any of the benefits of intellisense showing what methods are available for a given page.

Anyone know a good way around this?

Comment: Storing page objects in Cucumber World variables (e.g. @login_page) is considered a bad practice.  If you need a page, it is better to create one that to chase the state of @some_page around your Steps.  The Calabash docs and examples are not very good around this topic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found a way of getting this to work after much research and applying well known Java/C#/Obj-c principles to Ruby:

```
Given(/^I am on the launch page$/) do
  @launch_page ||= LaunchPage.new
end

When(/^I open the set alarm time page$/) do
  @set_alarm_page = @launch_page.goto_set_alarm_page
end

When(/^I open our apps from the home page$/) do
  @launch_page.navigation_toolbar.open_our_apps
end

Then(/^I should see the homepage alarm time is (\d+)$/) do |alarm_time|
  alarm_time_actual = @launch_page.get_alarm_time
  assert_equal(alarm_time, alarm_time_actual)
end
```

As long as somewhere on the step definition class you explicitly create a new page object (in the above example: LaunchPage.new), then all subsequent pages will provide intellisense method/property values, since the resulting page types returned will be known by RubyMine.

Answer (score 2):

As much as I appreciate and apply PO design pattern, as much I disagree with returning page object by page object. Page object should be independent and don't need to know about other page objects. Look at two examples:

- You test form validation. Click on submit button returns page object which is subsequent in the workflow, but in this case you remain on page with validation errors. Your page object won't know about it and will return the other page.
- Page which you get to after clicking a button may differ depending on the context (e.g. from what other page you got to current page). It can lead to having multiple versions of actually same method, which will return different page objects depending on context. This is not good and overcomplicates simple thing.

If you want to return current page object, you can benefit from it e.g. in Java, when you return `this` at the end of the method. Then you can chain all methods you execute as long as you are on the same page. But when it comes to the question 'how to implement returning different page objects' - answer is simple - 'just don't'. Please note wiki entry you quoted has not been updated for a good while and best practices has evolved since it was originally published.

Comment: When running automation projects with multiple testers, being able to 'string' pages together using code return types is invaluable.  Therefore, assuming I do want to return page objects, any ideas how?

Comment: Point 1 above: simply create two types of method (e.g. validSubmission() which returns next page and invalidSubmission() which returns the error page.   Point 2 above: simply create a private method in the class that performs the actions and call it from all public methods you need to. Very minor complication IMHO for the significant benefits of page stringing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you already have your solution. However for others and perhaps also for you the x-platform approach to calabash uses page objects so you could check out that implementation https://github.com/calabash/x-platform-example

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method would be as follows.  Not as neat as I would like (given the need to manually create new instances of subsequent pages), but available as an alternative option:

```
When(/^I buy a movie from the movie page$/) do
  movie_page = MoviePage.new
  movie_page.buyMovie("Test Movie")
  purchase_page = PurchasePage.new
  purchase_page.confirmPurchase
end
```